# Prolog Maze Runner

Tags: prolog, maze

You areasked to write a simple program in Prolog to find a path through a maze. Your 
input will consist of facts of the form 
pway(a, b, 10). 
indicating that there is a passageway from intersection a to intersection b of length 10 meters. 
You are to write a rule 
solve(X, Y, P, N) :- ... 
that will find a path   P   of length   N   (if one exists) from intersection   X   to intersection Y.  The intent 
is that the user will invoke    solve   as a query, specifying  X   and Y   as constants and    P   and N   as 
variables. 
Here is a concrete example. Suppose the database contains the following rules: 
pway(a, b, 10). 
pway(b, c, 15). 
pway(d, c, 5). 
pway(d, b, 10). 
If the user types 
solve(a, d, P, N) 
the Prolog interpreter might respond with 
P = [a, b, c, d] 
N = 30 If at this point the user types a semicolon, the interpreter should respond with 
P = [a, b, d] 
N = 20 
One more semicolon should produce 
no 
There are no more paths.

I have made this maze using the online interpreter

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/kb.pl

```
pway(a, b, 10).
pway(b, c, 15).
pway(d, c, 5).
pway(d, b, 10).
pway(c, d, 20).
pway(a, c, 25).
pway(b, a, 30).
solve(a, b, []).
solve(X, Y, P, N):- pway(a,[]),
not(member(a, b)), 
    solve(a, b).
solve(a, b, N):- pway(a, b),
not(member(a, b, N)), 
    solve(b, a, N).
solve(a, b, N):- (pway(a, b) ; pway(b, a)),
not(member(b, N)), solve(a, b, P, N).
sovle(a, b, P, N).
```

Note that passageways are bi-directional; if you can walk 10 meters from a to b, you can
also walk 10 meters from b toa.
2. Most mazes will have cycles. Your code must cope with them. There's no point in
passing through the same intersection more than once, and you certainly don't want the
interpreter to fall into an infinite regression doing so.
3. Note that the bi-directionality of passageways creates a huge number of trivial cycles:
you'll want to avoid walking from a to b and back to a again.

You shouldn't need to use any imperative features of Prolog (the cut,   fail,   or
database    ordering)   for this work. In fact, you shouldn't even need not, though you'll 
probably want \=     (numeric ``not equal''). A solution for the assignment consisting of 
only seven rules does exist!
3. You'll want to add distances. Remember that you must use the is  predicate to force
arithmetic computation.
4. generating all possible solutions, sorting them, and then producing them one-by-one on
demand. Other approaches may be easier, however. You may need the use of cut and fail
for the this part of the work.

When I run code i am getting these error. [image]

Comment: anyone can guide me where I am getting error and whats the wrong with this code....

Comment: your last clause says `sovle` instead of `solve`

Comment: I am getting errors

Comment: @firefrorefiddle I am getting error as I mentioned the above. plz check

Comment: @firefrorefiddle I am trying to make a maze in prolog to find the path. The fact of the path will be as    
pway(a,b,10) indicating that there is a passageway from intersection a to b of lenght 10 meter. The roles should be looks like this "solve(X,Y,P,N):- .... that will find a path p of the length N(if any one exist) fro mintersection X to intersection Y. The intent is that the user will invoke solve as a query, specify X and Y as constant and P and N as the variable. If the user types 
solve(a, d, P, N) 
the Prolog interpreter might respond with 
P = [a, b, c, d] 
N = 30

Comment: In addition to what @firefrorefiddle found, you also have a 4-argument `solve`, then a 3-argument `solve`, and then another 4-argument `solve`. As a result, Prolog is ignoring the first copy of `solve/4` altogether. If you meant to do that, you need to put the ones with the same number of arguments together or add the `:- discontiguous solve/3, solve/4.` instruction. If you didn't mean to do that, you need to sort out what arguments are missing or extra.

Comment: @DanielLyons  I am trying to make a maze in prolog to find the path. The fact of the path will be as pway(a,b,10) indicating that there is a passageway from intersection a to b of lenght 10 meter. The roles should be looks like this "solve(X,Y,P,N):- .... that will find a path p of the length N(if any one exist) fro mintersection X to intersection Y. The intent is that the user will invoke solve as a query, specify X and Y as constant and P and N as the variable. If the user types solve(a, d, P, N) the Prolog interpreter might respond with P = [a, b, c, d] N = 30 – so what will the code?

Comment: anyone can help in this work?

Comment: No one here to help me?

Comment: You already have the help you need. You need to read and understand it.